# Show flyout on clicking an item

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

in Metro app, how to show a flyout when user click on the child element of a ListView item. I mean a flyout should be showed when user click on "item-overlay" of the below ListView item. The problem I meet is metro ListView doesn't provide an event method for me to get that DOM in itemInvoked.

HTML

```
<!-- Detail items -->
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
    <div class="item-overlay">
        <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: shortTitle; id: key"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS. This is itemInvoked event of ListView item

```
itemInvoked: function (args) {
    console.log("groupItems:itemInvoked");
    if (appView.value === appViewState.snapped) {
        // If the page is snapped, the user invoked a group.
        var group = Data.groups.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);
        nav.navigate("/pages/groupDetail/groupDetail.html", { groupKey: group.key });
    } else {
        // If the page is not snapped, the user invoked an item.
        var item = Data.items.getAt(args.detail.itemIndex);

        nav.navigate("/pages/itemDetail/itemDetail.html", { item: Data.getItemReference(item) });
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add the win-interactive to the container to ensure that the list view doesn't swallow any interactions with the element.

that stated, given your handler, why are you even going down that path, doesn't the default invoked stuff give you what you nee?